# Asp.net configuring the default sent email

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to create a password recovery system in asp.net wbforms and I managed to do just that aldo the email sent is cryptic and I do not understand what should the new password be:

This is what I am recieving:

```
   X-Sender: forum@forum.com
X-Receiver: aly_aleczandru@yahoo.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: forum@forum.com
To: aly_aleczandru@yahoo.com
Date: 27 Nov 2012 13:41:57 +0200
Subject: Password
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Please return to the site and log in using the following informat=
ion.=0AUser Name: aleczandru=0APassword: c/x5jCAP;.x:T#=0A=0A
```

It seems that the old password is not working any more I have tryed this : c/x5jCAP;.x:T#=0A=0A but it does not work.In this case what should the new password be?
And how can I configure this email to make it a bit more user friendly?

Comment: `=0A` is a line-break in a quoted-printable message. If you open the message in a standard email client, you should see the body of the message decoded, and the password should be more obvious.

Comment: Thanks I managed to figure that out after about 3 hours of surfing the internet could you please post an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=0A` is a line-break in a quoted-printable message. If you open the message in a standard email client, you should see the body of the message decoded, and the password should be more obvious.